# Trigger Javascript Event on Add to DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

Does anyone know how to trigger an event in Javascript for an element after it has been added to the DOM?

The general idea is something like this:

```
var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.addEventListener('ON_ADD_TO_BODY', function(){console.log(elem.parentNode)});
//... LATER ON ...
parentElemInBody.appendChild(elem); // <- Event is triggered here after append
```

There are some functions that shouldn't be triggered until you add the element to the DOM so it would make sense to delay execution until the element is added.

Is there a way to do this without explicitly needing to call them later on or should I be doing some hack that includes a `setTimeout` and a check to see if the element has been added to the DOM yet?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the **DOMNodeInserted** mutation event.

Docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events

Example usage as given in the above page:

```
element.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (ev) {
  // ...
}, false);
```

**Note: 17th April, 2016**

Mutation Events are deprecated as of now. The recommended approach now is  [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: I didn't know those even existed! I do need to support IE9- though :( and those comments on performance hits aren't very reassuring. I know I didn't specify that in the question so your answer is correct but I do need to take all of it into consideration. Is there a hybrid approach that, at the very least, supports IE9-?

Comment: For browsers that don't support the above, you might need to roll out a timer which periodically checks the children of the parent element and trigger some callback.